# Работа с COM портом В PHP, при чтении данных получаю не все данные

Tags: php, port, serial, rs232

Использую библиотеку php_serial для работы с GSM модулем (MC39i).

Все отлично, кроме одного - получения списка смс.

Если ответ большой, то приходит не все смс, обрезаются в конце.

Пример:

```
<?php

include "app/lib/php_serial/php_serial.php";

$port = new PhpSerial();
$port->deviceSet('/dev/ttyACM0');
$port->confBaudRate(115200);

$port->deviceOpen('a+b');

$port->sendMessage("AT+CMGF=0\r", 0.1);
$port->sendMessage("AT+CMEE=2\r", 0.1);
$port->sendMessage("ATV\r");
$port->sendMessage("ATE0\r");
$port->readPort();

$port->sendMessage("AT+CMGL=4\r", 3);

$data = $port->readPort();

var_dump($data);
```

В ответ получаю 8 смсок,

```
string(1216) "
+CMGL: 1,1,,23

0791973007038...

+CMGL: 2,1,,64

07919730071111F1...

+CMGL: 3,1,,64

07919730071111F1...

+CMGL: 4,1,,64

07919730071111F1...

+CMGL: 5,1,,64

07919730071111F1...

+CMGL: 6,1,,64

07919730071111F1...

+CMGL: 7,1,,64

07919730071111F1...

+CMGL: 8,1,,64

07919730071111F1...
"
```

В конце нет ответа ОК (в данном случае 0).
Если же зайти через minicom (или putty), то в ответ приходит 11 смсок с кодом ОК.

```
+CMGL: 1,1,,23
07919730070386F70...
+CMGL: 2,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 3,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 4,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 5,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 6,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 7,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 8,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 9,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 10,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
+CMGL: 11,1,,64
07919730071111F10...
0
```

Пробовал другие режимы (AT+CMGF=1) - приходит еще меньше смс...
Также пробовал менять параметры: parity, flow control, ставил больший таймаут -- ничего не меняется.

Модем подключен через USB, ОСь - ubuntu 14.04

Подскажите, куда копать?